# Is that Possible to Add and Get values after first slash in a URL in core PHP?

Tags: php, tinyurl

Is that possible in Core PHP that I can get the value `as2256` on my index page from this URL

```
domain.com/as2256
```

When I am doing this, getting error that

> The requested URL /as2256 was not found on this server.

I am working on short URL, so what is the proper method to get it.

Comment: you should read about nginx/apache rewrites

Comment: This isn’t calling your “index page” to begin with, that’s _why_ you get a 404. And “core PHP” alone can not make the web server handle non-existing resources differently on its own, this will need some sort of server-side configuration or other (there’s multiple ways to achieve this.)

Comment: please update question with what you have tried yet